# convert yaml to json payload - iterate over yaml objects and have different json payloads

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, yaml

I have figured out that i can convert yaml to json pretty easily.  Which will allow me to have the payload of to be created and sent from the yaml file and updated there as well.

What am i trying to accomplish?
Ideally i have multiple objects within a yaml file which i need to iterate over.  Each time i iterate over them they need to be sent as a payload for an api request.  I would like to convert the yaml to json and provide that as the payload vs doing the for loop and setting all the values manually.

sample.yaml

```
Component: 'users'
user:
  username: 'rhendricks'
  email: 'rich@piedpiper.com'
  receiveNotifications: False
  firstName: 'Richard'
  lastName: 'Hendricks'
  password: 'Pass321!'
  roles: 
    - id: 105
    - id: 106 
user:
  username: 'dinesh'
  email: 'dinesh@piedpiper.com'
  receiveNotifications: False
  firstName: 'Dinesh'
  lastName: 'Chugtai'
  password: 'Pass321!'
  roles:
    - id: 105
```

Above is the sample yaml file i am working with.

what the api payload is expecting:

```
spayload = json.dumps({
                'user':{
                    'username': username,
                    'email': email,
                    'firstName': firstName,
                    'lastName': lastName,
                    'password': password,
                    'recieveNotifications': receiveNotifications,
                    'roles': [
                        {'id': 106},
                        {'id': 105}
                    ]
                }
            })
```

My current method for setting up the payload is something like the following - this is an example of another payload.  If i can't figure out another way i will result to the following.

```
 for k, v in result['groups'].items():
        name = result['groups'][k]['name']
        description = result['groups'][k]['description']
        location = result['groups'][k]['location']
        code = result['groups'][k]['code']
        payload = json.dumps({
                                "group":{
                                  "name": name,
                                  "description": description,
                                  "location": location,
                                  "code": code
                                }
                              })
```

Here is my current testing:

```
import json
import re
import urllib
import urllib3
import yaml
import requests
import glob
from . import morph_log
def createUser(yaml_file):
    logger = morph_log.get_logger('createUser')
    files = glob.glob(yaml_file)
    for file in files: 
        yaml_file = file 
        logger.info('Current file: '+yaml_file)

        with open(yaml_file) as f:
            try:
                result=yaml.safe_load(f)
            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                logger.error(exc)
                logger.error('Was unable to load the file')
        os_list={}
        with open(yaml_file) as infile:
            os_list = yaml.load(infile, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        print(json.dumps(os_list))
        yaml_file = open(yaml_file, 'r')
        result = yaml_file.readlines()
        del result[0]
        print(result)
       # for key, value in yaml.load(result, Loader=yaml.FullLoader).items():
      #      print('key', key)

        for value in result:
            print('Entry', value)
            #print('entry:', value['user'])
            #print(entry['username'])
            #print('Sub', entry['users'])

        for key, value in result['user'].items():
           # username = value['username']
            print('Key', key)
            print('User', value )
```

I am also trying to drop the component line as i start to process as the api doesn't understand that construct.  I use that component element as a way to process the file correctly.

The example yaml file as 2 payloads that i need to be able to send.

Here is my log of what i have so far.

```
2022-02-04 21:51:43,585:25:users:createUser:INFO:Current file: contentpacks/piedPiper/users.yaml
{"Component": "users", "user": {"username": "dinesh", "email": "dinesh@piedpiper.com", "receiveNotifications": false, "firstName": "Dinesh", "lastName": "Chugtai", "password": "Pass321!", "roles": [{"id": 105}]}}
['user:\n', "  username: 'rhendricks'\n", "  email: 'rich@piedpiper.com'\n", '  receiveNotifications: False\n', "  firstName: 'Richard'\n", "  lastName: 'Hendricks'\n", "  password: 'Pass321!'\n", '  roles: \n', '    - id: 105\n', '    - id: 106    # needs to be some sort of list. \n', 'user:\n', "  username: 'dinesh'\n", "  email: 'dinesh@piedpiper.com'\n", '  receiveNotifications: False\n', "  firstName: 'Dinesh'\n", "  lastName: 'Chugtai'\n", "  password: 'Pass321!'\n", '  roles:\n', '    - id: 105']
Entry user:

Entry   username: 'rhendricks'

Entry   email: 'rich@piedpiper.com'

Entry   receiveNotifications: False

Entry   firstName: 'Richard'

Entry   lastName: 'Hendricks'

Entry   password: 'Pass321!'

Entry   roles: 

Entry     - id: 105

Entry     - id: 106    # needs to be some sort of list. 

Entry user:

Entry   username: 'dinesh'

Entry   email: 'dinesh@piedpiper.com'

Entry   receiveNotifications: False

Entry   firstName: 'Dinesh'

Entry   lastName: 'Chugtai'

Entry   password: 'Pass321!'

Entry   roles:

Entry     - id: 105
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 21, in <module>
    cpack_utility.contentPack_file_processor(contentPackSelection)
  File "/home/ubuntu/implementation/cpack_utility/contentPack_processing.py", line 149, in contentPack_file_processor
    contentPack_implementation(contentPackSelection)
  File "/home/ubuntu/implementation/cpack_utility/contentPack_processing.py", line 62, in contentPack_implementation
    users.createUser(yaml_file)
  File "/home/ubuntu/implementation/cpack_utility/users.py", line 50, in createUser
    for key, value in result['user'].items():
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Since i will expect the payload to be a certain way i will no doubt have to add this to my yaml validation scripts.  That parts pretty easy.

any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In YAML, it is an error to have multiple identical keys in a mapping. Your root mapping has `user` two times. This is not allowed.

It is a bit hard to figure out what you want to do, but I believe you're searching for multi-document YAML files:

```yaml
Component: 'users'
---
user:
  username: 'rhendricks'
  email: 'rich@piedpiper.com'
  receiveNotifications: False
  firstName: 'Richard'
  lastName: 'Hendricks'
  password: 'Pass321!'
  roles: 
    - id: 105
    - id: 106
---
user:
  username: 'dinesh'
  email: 'dinesh@piedpiper.com'
  receiveNotifications: False
  firstName: 'Dinesh'
  lastName: 'Chugtai'
  password: 'Pass321!'
  roles:
    - id: 105
```

`---` is a *directives end marker* which in this case effectively separates multiple YAML documents. Each document contains a root mapping with the sole key `user`.

This minimal script:

```py
import yaml, json
import sys

with open("sample.yaml") as file:
    content = iter(yaml.safe_load_all(file))
    next(content) # skip first document
    for doc in content:
        json.dump(doc, sys.stdout, indent=2)
        print("\n---")
```

Will then produce:

```json
{
  "user": {
    "username": "rhendricks",
    "email": "rich@piedpiper.com",
    "receiveNotifications": false,
    "firstName": "Richard",
    "lastName": "Hendricks",
    "password": "Pass321!",
    "roles": [
      {
        "id": 105
      },
      {
        "id": 106
      }
    ]
  }
}
---
{
  "user": {
    "username": "dinesh",
    "email": "dinesh@piedpiper.com",
    "receiveNotifications": false,
    "firstName": "Dinesh",
    "lastName": "Chugtai",
    "password": "Pass321!",
    "roles": [
      {
        "id": 105
      }
    ]
  }
}
---
```

Comment: So i think you are close to what i am trying to accomplish.  Ideally i would like to for each one of those documents and assign them to the var payload and then send the payload with the request to the api.

Comment: i get the following error with the above code. 

yaml.composer.ComposerError: expected a single document in the stream
  in "contentpacks/piedPiper/users.yaml", line 1, column 1
but found another document
  in "contentpacks/piedPiper/users.yaml", line 2, column 1

Comment: ```
Component: "users"
---
user:
  username: "rhendricks"
  email: "rich@piedpiper.com"
  receiveNotifications: False
  firstName: "Richard"
  lastName: "Hendricks"
  password: "Pass321!"
  roles:
    - id: 105
    - id: 106 # needs to be some sort of list.
---
user:
  username: "dinesh"
  email: "dinesh@piedpiper.com"
  receiveNotifications: False
  firstName: "Dinesh"
  lastName: "Chugtai"
  password: "Pass321!"
  roles:
    - id: 105
```

Comment: @Jared you need `yaml.safe_load_all` or `yaml.load_all` for multi-document YAML files.